# Stacking dataframe columns (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I am looking for a way to pivot a dataframe in reverse direction. To the best of my knowledge, pandas provides a pivot or pivot_table method to transform an EAV df to a "normal" one. However, is there also a way to do the inverse?

So given the dataframe:

`$df
userid A   B  C
0      1   1  0
1      1   3  1
2      1   5  0`

I would like to transform it to (a EAV model):

`$df
E  A  V

0  A  1
0  B  1
0  C  0
1  A  1
1  B  3
1  C  1
2  A  1
2  B  5
2  C  0`

What would be the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `userid` is the index, `df.stack` will do it:

```
In [133]: df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'userid' : 'E', 'level_1' : 'A', 0 : 'V'})
Out[133]: 
   E  A  V
0  0  A  1
1  0  B  1
2  0  C  0
3  1  A  1
4  1  B  3
5  1  C  1
6  2  A  1
7  2  B  5
8  2  C  0
```

If `userid` is not the index, set it like this:

```
df.set_index('userid', inplace=True)
```